# Not able to remove duplicate cases from Junit Report Cucumber

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jenkins, cucumber, testng, junit4

I have two junits reports with cucumber.xml and cucumber1.xml, these are generated, when I triggered Main Cucumber class (then cucumber.xml created )and run my another cucumber class which only containing the failed scenarios reported execution of main cucumber class.

I am not able remove the duplicates as after merging both the Junit Files, providing me additional count of total cases

As lets say - Total cases - 100 Passed 90 Failed 10
Rerun only 10 - Total cases 10 Passed 9 Failed 1

after this my Total count of cases coming as Total cases - 110 - Passed - 99, Failed 11

While it should report - Total cases 100, Passed 99, Failed 1

Any help would be appreciated.